# tcolorbox and figures - adding description

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox

I want to style my figures and I found a way to do so with tcolorbox.

```
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,blend before title=colon hang,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1,sharp corners,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!30!black}

\begin{myfigure}{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Graphic} 
\end{myfigure}
```

Is there a possibility to add some text besides the graphic?

---

Thank you for your answers.

So here's the MWE showing one standard figure with a subtext and a tcolorbox-figure. What I want to do is adding some text inside the tcolorbox, too. This text should be under (maybe the best way) or on one side the graphic - but inside the colorbox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox, blend before title=colon hang,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1,sharp corners,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!30!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Graphic} 
\caption{Title}
\footnotesize{Subtext Line 1 \\ Subtext Line 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{myfigure}{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Graphic} 
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible) to form a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What does `besides the graphics` mean? Inside the colorbox? Outside it?

Comment: Does 'besides' mean 'in addition to' or 'to one side of' the graphic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem adding any text to a `myfigure` contents. So OP could use something like:

```
\begin{myfigure}{Title}
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Graphic} 

\footnotesize{Subtext Line 1 \\ Subtext Line 2}
\end{myfigure}
```

but the result is not as desired because OP's `myfigure` contains option `capture=hbox` which means:

> This is the default `<mode>` for `\tcbox`. The content cannot have a lower part and
>   cannot be broken. The colored box is sized according to the dimensions of the content.
>   A shortcut to set this mode is `/tcb/hbox`.

We have two solutions, use `capture=hbox` and include and manually format image and contents or change to `capture=minipage` (the default mode) and let `tcolorbox` do the work for us. With the second solution,

- it's still possible (although manually) to adjust box width: `width=...`
- it's possible to use the `lower` part of a `tcolorbox` for comments
- option `sidebyside` moves comments from lower part to figure side

Following code shows a possible declaration for `myfigure` and how particular options change the defined behaviour.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{%
    float=htb,
    blend before title=colon hang,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=blue!30!black,
    title={#2},
    every float=\centering,
    halign=flush center,
    halign lower=flush center,
    lower separated=false,
    #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfigure}{A tcolorbox figure}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
\tcblower
This is a comment to the figure placed inside the colored box
\end{myfigure}

\begin{myfigure}[sidebyside]{A tcolorbox figure}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
\tcblower
This is a comment to the figure placed inside the colored box
\end{myfigure}

\begin{myfigure}[width=8cm]{A tcolorbox figure}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
\tcblower
This is a comment to the figure placed inside the colored box
\end{myfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer @Ignasi. How would you reference the figure? I tried putting `\label{fig}` inside the environment, inside the title, and below `\tcblower` without success. If it's worth a new question, I'll make one. Thanks.

Comment: I found a workaround, but it's not based on `tcolorbox`, so there's probably better. Preamble: `\makeatletter \newcommand\addcaption[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption} \makeatother` Inside figure: `\addcaption{figure}{This is a title to the figure}\label{fig1}`

Comment: @PatrickT After including `label=whateverlabelyoulike` into the optional parameter, you can use `\red{whateverlabelyoulike`. You can see examples in section 5 of tcolorbox documentation

Comment: Got it thanks Ignasi!